# Clear View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I am calling the function `setLayoutData()` for many places i want to clear the view whenever it is called.What is happening now the layout get appends .But i don't want to append how can we clear the view .Please help me this is my function

```
void setLayoutData() {
        resultTrips = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.trip_list);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainTripDetailsLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
            final LinearLayout tripdetailsdata = (LinearLayout) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.mytripinner, null);
            tripdetailsdata.setId(i);
            resultTrips.addView(tripdetailsdata);
            i++;
        }
        TextView dummy = new TextView(this);
        dummy.setLayoutParams(mainTripDetailsLayout);
        resultTrips.addView(dummy);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to clear your LinearLayout?
so put in your second line after findView... `resultTrips.removeAllViews();`

The better aproach would be only adding one TextView to your Linearlayout and edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resultTips.removeAllViews();` to remove the resultTips layout or `resultTips.removeView(dummy);` to remove the TextView. Hope it helps.